# Iterating through a nested json Model using Jsrender

Tags: jquery, python, jsrender

I have the following json sent from a server and i have been trying to make iterate it with jsrender with no success

```
{
"1": {
    "username": "one",
    "sent_email": false,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "email",
    "date_registered": null,
    "key": "key",
    "password": "password",
    "id": 1
},
"2": {
    "username": "Madawar",
    "sent_email": true,
    "group": "admin",
    "date_activated": "2012-07-17T00:00:00",
    "activated_email": true,
    "email": "dennis.wanyoike@gmail.com",
    "date_registered": "2012-08-22T11:21:39",
    "key": "e4hVRItub_A=",
    "password": "$2a$12$F3aBLpF.MyyiVDAocPzE9uJn0K5DZ1V4qRim54wl8f3tEv.7VC4ji",
    "id": 2
},
"3": {
    "username": "one",
    "sent_email": false,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "email",
    "date_registered": null,
    "key": "key",
    "password": "password",
    "id": 3
},
"4": {
    "username": "one",
    "sent_email": false,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "email",
    "date_registered": null,
    "key": "key",
    "password": "password",
    "id": 4
},
"5": {
    "username": "one",
    "sent_email": false,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "email",
    "date_registered": null,
    "key": "key",
    "password": "password",
    "id": 5
},
"6": {
    "username": "one",
    "sent_email": false,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "email",
    "date_registered": null,
    "key": "key",
    "password": "password",
    "id": 6
},
"7": {
    "username": "one",
    "sent_email": false,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "email",
    "date_registered": null,
    "key": "key",
    "password": "password",
    "id": 7
},
"10": {
    "username": "Madawar12",
    "sent_email": true,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": "dennis.wanyoike@gmail12.com",
    "date_registered": "2012-08-30T17:13:07",
    "key": "JehBfVpoheE=",
    "password": "$2a$12$V04xpEqCWSLIWl0rte2U7OQC5/TqFcDehKJiuiqRALiW3uEYTBFsK",
    "id": 10
},
"11": {
    "username": null,
    "sent_email": true,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": null,
    "date_registered": "2012-08-30T17:16:32",
    "key": "MG7kgSUzNK0=",
    "password": "$2a$12$6gJa1L0MZn9HB/fZNk1cXe1RDjAIOaAv1ASTgBJu.OrhOMpNfCkOG",
    "id": 11
},
"12": {
    "username": null,
    "sent_email": true,
    "group": "blogger",
    "date_activated": null,
    "activated_email": false,
    "email": null,
    "date_registered": "2012-08-30T17:17:30",
    "key": "qJisSUS8osQ=",
    "password": "$2a$12$tfDdBODJFTz/afhAvm7EjOpH.Zp.Q8Jw.h312uFZCwJQTlKRI0k6G",
    "id": 12
}
```

}

The numbers 1-12 represent record numbers and are not necessarily sequential, is it possible to display this record with jsrender or do i have to change the result from the server?

Answer (score 3):

To give you some ideas, take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html) which shows a couple of approaches in JsRender to iterating through fields. You could apply those methods to your scenario. (The live demo is [here](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html)).

***Update***: Current docs are here: http://www.jsviews.com/#propstag.

As to iterating to any depth, you can indeed use `{{props}}` in either templates or tags which are used recursively - and so traverse a hierarchy of arrays and objects to any depth.

There is a `{{jsonview/}}` tag [coded here](//www.jsviews.com/download/sample-tag-controls/jsonview/jsonview.js) which does just that, and is used in [this jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/dg7x8mrc/), for example...

In this case is it using data-linking, so when you change the data in any way in the 'tree', the jsonview output updates incrementally. The same {{jsonview}} can be used with just JsRender. (You can change the data-linked `{^{...}}` tags to just `{{...}}` if you want, in that scenario.)

Comment: This is a great start but I failed to manage to get a infinite depth solution.

Comment: @Blowsie Why do you need infinite depth solution?

Comment: @GradientByte For nested data structures like trees

Comment: @Blowsie he added a well defined json, not a tree. if you want infinite depth solution you can try with recursively calling a template inside a template ([see here](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/tmpl))

Comment: @GradientByte thanks, but I was just simply highlighting a potential issue with the solution, over three years ago now anyway

Comment: @Blowsie - Yes, certainly a template using {{props}} can be called recursively - and can traverse a tree to any depth. I added a couple of links above

Answer (score 0):

You can render this as below

var collection = json
$.each(collection, function(key,value){
alert(key + "-----"+ value);
$.each(value,function(k,v){ alert(k+"++++++++"+v)});
});

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it works but do you have any idea how i would render the json using jsrender?

Comment: Also, the overhead of using jQuery's `.each()` function is not necessary. A regular javascript for loop would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I Used @BorisMoore's answer and made a template that just puts everything in your JSON into a table:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="prooops">
  <table>
    {{props #data}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{>key}}</td>
        <td>
          {{props prop}}
            {{>key}}: {{>prop}}<br/>
          {{/props}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/props}}
  </table>
</script>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gradient/rfjwsq7y/) is a jsFiddle to show you how it works.

To be fair this is a 4 year old question now, I doubt you still have this problem. Just put it here to show the future generations how it's done